# Sorting Functionality

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have a dropdown menu with values Sort by Laggards & Sort 
     by: Achievers
    which should get sorted with ascending data for (laggards) & descending data for (Achievers)

HTML Code:

```
<select ng-model="sortValueDropdown" ng-change="sortBy()">
  <option value="Sort by:Laggards" selected>Sort by: {{ Laggards | order }}
  </option>
  <option value="Sort by:Achievers">Sort by: Achievers
  </option>
</select>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$scope.laggards = [
  {"name":"NOP","No":"1000"},
  {"name":"NOP","No":"1200"},
  {"name":"NOP","No":"5000"}
];

$scope.achievers = [
  {"name":"NOP","No":"2500"},
  {"name":"NOP","No":"1280"},
  {"name":"NOP","No":"5600"}
];

$scope.sortBy = function() {
  $scope.sortVal = $scope.sortValueDropdown;

  alert($scope.sortVal);

  if($scope.sortVal == 'Laggards') {            

  } else if($scope.sortVal == 'Achievers') {            

  }
}
```

I have the above code. Please let me know how to sort this data with sort function. I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function of javascript to achieve this.
example:
For Laggards:

```
 $scope.laggards.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.No - b.No;
 });
```

For Achievers:

```
 $scope.achievers.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.No - b.No;
 });
```